# Regarding terraform script behaviour

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform scripts to create azure services, I am having some doubts regarding Terraform,

```
1) If I have one environment let say dev in azure having some azure resources how can I copy all the resources to new environment lest say prod using terraform script.

2)what are the impact of re-run the terraform file with additional azure resources, what it will do.

3)What if I want to create an app service with the same name from Terraform script that already present in the azure will it update the resource or do nothing after terraform execution completed.
```

Please feel free to answer the question, it will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You could create a new workspace with [terraform workspace new](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/workspace/new.html) and copy all configuration files (`.tf`) to the new environment, then run terraform init, plan, apply.
2. The terraform will compare the content in your current state file with your configuration file, then update the new attributes or creating new resources other than re-creating the existing resources.
3. You could run [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) to import existing infrastructure into Terraform. For referencing existing resources in the portal, you can use [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html).

Comment: thanx for the reply, for the first comment in my case I have created manually one resource group and one app service inside it using azure portal, now I want to copy this infrastructure to other environment using terraform script, can you please help me in this scenario

Comment: What do you mean in other environments? Is that environment in the same subscription and tenant as the current environment? Terraform deployed resource depends on the configuration files, If you have the configuration files, you can reproduce the infrastructure except for the same resource name(conflict).

Comment: Suppose I need to deploy on the other azure subscription then how can I deploy using terraform file

Comment: You can define the subscription id when you use `provider "azurerm" ` like [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/azure_cli.html#configuring-azure-cli-authentication-in-terraform) or if you want to optionally define multiple configurations for the same provider, and select which one to use on a per-resource or per-module basis, you can use alias like [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations).

Comment: ok got it, my question is how to copy the Infrastructure that was created manually on azure portal

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct copy resource with terraform from one subscription to another subscription, you need to deploy the resource with terraform init, plan, apply.from the new subscription.

Comment: Ok, One question when we run our terraform script to create azure resource using azure devops, where does terraform .tf state file created.

Comment: It will store at `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example:` c:\agent_work\1\s`. refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services)